# django-storages and boto ImproperlyConfigured

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, boto

I am getting this error when my django powered website attempts a file upload:

```
ImproperlyConfigured at /~~~
Could not load Boto's S3 bindings.
See https://github.com/boto/boto
```

I have investigated and found that the line `from boto import __version__ as boto_version` fails. Removing the surrounding try-catch statement gives this error:

```
Error importing module storages.backends.s3boto: "cannot import name __version__"
```

This usually indicates a circular import but I cannot seem to find one. Using the django shell (invoked using: `python manage.py shell`), I can import and manipulate boto and S3BotoStorage as one would expect to. I am unable to recreate this error outside of the page rendering.

I have the most recent versions of boto and django-storages and storages is added to INSTALLED_APPS.

```
$ pip show boto django-storages
---
Name: boto
Version: 2.30.0
...
---
Name: django-storages
Version: 1.1.8
... 
$ python manage.py shell
>>> import boto
>>> boto.__version__
'2.30.0'
>>> from storages.backends.s3boto import S3BotoStorage
>>> b = S3BotoStorage()
>>> b.get_available_name('foo')
'foo'
$ cat settings.py | grep 'storages'
INSTALLED_APPS += ('storages',)
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto.S3BotoStorage'
```

What is causing this error, how can it be fixed, and thank you for any help you give.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem and I'm not sure why this fixed the issue but I upgraded boto to version 2.31.1 and everything started working again. Hope this helps:

```
pip install boto --upgrade
```

Comment: Thanks, I am now experiencing other issues, but the one I posted about is gone.